# How to convert a cvCvtColor to cvtColor call in opencv (BGR to HSV)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using a C++ code with old version of opencv that uses this to convert BGR to HSV -

```
cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
```

where frame and imgHSV are IplImage* objects

The newer versions of opencv don't have this method and I found cvtColor() in imgproc that does the same. But this method uses cv::InputArray and cv::OutputAray formats for parameters instead of IplImage* . How do I convert and convert back the IplImage* formats to these new formats? Any other way to convert from BGR to HSV for IplImage* that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2):

use cv::Mat instead of IplImage here, in general, prefer the c++ api to the deprecated c-api:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("my.png");

cv::Mat hsv;
cv::cvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::imshow("hsv",hsv);
cv::waitKey();
```

Comment: I actually need IplImage*, or else I'd have to change many things. I simply did #include <opencv/cv.h> and the older code works now.

Comment: please change "many things" and stop using the deprecated c-api ! it's only around for maintenance , you should not write any new code like this.

Comment: @berak are you saying IplImage is deprecated? I was doing some research on which data type to use, and this fact would make it a no brainer.

Comment: yes. please avoid using anything from opencv's arcane c-api.